# Ubuntu starts with commanline messages

Tags: boot

I have Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS which was updated from 20.04 LTS. During my last few days 20.04, Ubuntu used to boot by showing messages rather than the usual loading screen that comes up with the ubuntu name and logo. Then I updated it 22.04.1 LTS and it still boots up by showing the messages. A screenshot of messages are below:-

[image]

Is there any way with which I can boot up ubuntu with the loading screen rather than this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem should have been fixed before the upgrade. An upgrade never fixes a broken system.  As for the picture of the text it is so fuzzy I can not read it and I do not think others will be able to either.

Comment: Have you looked at your grub config and whether it has disabled the splash screen?

Comment: @Crighton, how does one check for that?

Comment: GIYF.  Look up <https://www.howtogeek.com/196655/how-to-configure-the-grub2-boot-loaders-settings/> which takes you through this. I use nano as the editor. if you use '-bw' flags it keeps a copy of the file before you edit it.